# SQL Server - Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup, restore, sql-server-2019

Took backup of database from `SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise` and trying to restore it on a database on `SQL Server 2019 Enterprise` but getting error:

```
Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use
```

I took destination database offline but no luck. Restarted SQL Server service but no luck. `Close existing connections to destination database` is checked under `Options` but no luck (screenshot attached). There is enough disk space available.

Is the error coming due to version difference? If yes, then how to restore database from 2008 R2 to 2019?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps restoring with tail and leave source will need the exclusive access. Have you tried to uncheck both

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite the existing database on the 2019 server or restore the backup as a new copy of the database?

Comment: Existing database which I just created.

Comment: Does checking off "*Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)*" fix your issue? Also if it's a new database you just created then presumably there's nothing to backup and you can uncheck "*Take tail-log backup before restore*".

Comment: Restarted server, then checked `Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)` and also removed tail log checkbox and this time it worked